# How to target one class with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code:

```
 $("img").hover(function() {
  $(".portfolio4").stop().animate({opacity: "0.8"}, 'slow');
},
function() {
  $(".portfolio4").stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 'slow');
});
```

I am making a gallery which is responsive, so I am using the div with the class "portfolio4" to hold all my images.

When I use the above code and hover over one image, then it fades out ALL of the portfolio4's 
when I only want it to just fade out the actual div that the image is nested inside of.

Hope that makes sense?

Any help would be much appreciated. I know it will be something simple but I am not sure how to change it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get to the enclosing div  :

```
$("img").hover(function() {
  $(this).closest(".portfolio4").stop().animate({opacity: "0.8"}, 'slow');
},
function() {
  $(this).closest(".portfolio4").stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: closest is better in case the html structure changes a bit

Comment: the only case I could see it breaking would be if the hovered img had 2 ancestors with the `.portfolio4` class. Am I confused?

Comment: @ZachL What would be the advantage of parents ? closest do just what is needed.

Comment: @ZachL - yes you are confused, `closest()` finds the closest matching parent, while `parents()` finds all matching parents, all the way up to `<html>`

Comment: ah thanks. not sure why I had a block on that, even after reading docs.

Comment: Thanks people. I will use closest then in this instance.
Also, is there a way to stop the img fading out to nothing as I realise that when I fade out my parent div then the img is also fading. Is there a way to get around this or will I have to restructure things?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img").hover(function() {
  $(this).parents(".portfolio4").stop().animate({opacity: "0.8"}, 'slow');
},
function() {
  $(this).parents(".portfolio4").stop().animate({opacity: "1"}, 'slow');
});
```